# Azure Logic App - ActionFailed error while using variable and working with loop

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created the following flow for delete the blob by comparing the following conditions in azure logic app.

1. If Blob name is present in the backup folder(represent by List1)
2. If Blob is older than 24 hours

Here I have used variable initialized with the expression for blob older than 24 hours.

[Variable Initialization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoKqR.png)

Here I am giving the condition(Note: List contains backup folder blob list and List Blobs2 contains blobs to be deleted folder blob list)
[condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jutW.png)

And here is the execution screenshot where it is throwing an error ActionFailed
[ActionFailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6FNC.png)

Note: The blob is get deleted even if i have not put the check on the List Blob. On next iteration It is still giving that error and delete the blob. But my concern is I am not checking the 1st condition that I have mentioned above so why it gives me that error.
[next iteration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFbY7.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot you provided, it seems the problem was caused by "For each" run in parallel. The "For each" in logic app can run with just one instance or run in parallel, please change the setting of both two of your "For each" actions.

Click `...` button of your "For each" action and click "Settings", enable `Concurrency Control` and set the `Degree of Parallelism` to `1`.

[image]

We need to change this setting especially when there are nested "For each".

Comment: I checked with your solution. There is problem if outer loop or inner loop has multiple iterations. for only one iteration it works fine but not with the multiple iterations.

Comment: Not yet @Hury. Problem with multiple iterations